# Do field upgrades apply to all squad members in Battlefield 4?

Tags: battlefield-4, ps4

Do field upgrades apply to all squad members in Battlefield 4? By this I mean should each squad member select a different upgrade so that all squad members benefit? For example, if I upgrade to extra ammo does each member get the ammo boost?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No.

Your field upgrades are indeed shared by your team in a way, but there are three universal field upgrades that any class can equip: Defensive, Offensive, and Shadow. There is also two class-specific upgrades.
There are four tiers in each field upgrade, the first one being automatically introduced when you select the upgrade.

That being said, you can upgrade the rank of your field upgrades by doing squad-work, like reviving team-mates, repairing a vehicle, etc. This rank will be given to anyone in the squad who has the field upgrade.

So it may very well be worthwhile in getting the same field-upgrades or none at all, depending on your strategies and group playstyle.

There are 11 different field upgrades in Battlefield-4:

---

**1.**    Defensive: Armor – Cover – Flak – Quick regen

**2.**    Offensive: Print – Ammo – Grenades – Reduced Fall

**3.**    Shadow: Quick unspot – Sprint – Reduced Fall – Stealth

**4.**    Combat Medic: Medkit upgrade – Sprint – Defibrillator – Medical Unit

**5.**    Grenadier: Grenades – Sprint – 40mm grenades – Flak

**6.**    Anti-tank: Mines – Rockets – More deployed explosives – Flak

**7.**    Mechanic: Fast repair – Flak – Cover – Repair unit

**8.**    Indirect fire: Ammo box upgrade – Ammo – Indirect fire – Resupply unit

**9.**    Perimeter defense: Ammo – Suppression – Claymores – MP-APS

**10.**    Spec Ops: Stealth – C4 Explosives – Motion sensors – Quick unspot

**11.**    Sniper: Hold breath – Cover – Quick Unspot – Advanced spot

---